# Using dot notation in the WHERE clause of n1ql

Tags: syntax, couchbase, sql++

Does n1ql support dot notation to allow filtering results based on a JSON subfield's value?

Should one use `=` or `is` operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command can be used to filter on  a subfield:

```
SELECT * from `bucket` WHERE info.category = 'SPECIFIC_CATEGORY';
```

The [documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/4.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/comparisonops.html) explains when the `IS` operator should be used:

> The IS/IS NOT NULL/MISSING family of operators lets you specify conditions based on the existence (or absence) of attributes in a data set.

You might want run through the [N1QL Tutorial](http://query.pub.couchbase.com/).

Comment: Actually the '=' syntax seems to work for booleans, strings, and numbers on both the top level and lower levels. The 'is' syntax seems to work for strings, but not for booleans or numbers. Don't know if that is intended.

My initial problem had to do with a json field being named 'group'. :) As my co-worker has suggested, it may have been treated as a n1ql keyword.

Comment: yes the = operator should work on a subfield... you may have to escape part of your path if attributes in your json map to N1QL keywords, as you discovered later ;)